# Enable/disable buttons by the value of a text box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a text box in MainWindow.

```
<TextBox Name="txtCalls" Text="{Binding ElementName=sliderCalls,
            Path=Value,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="22"/>
```

Also I have two buttons: `btnStart` and `btnAbort`.

```
<Button x:Name="btnStart" Margin="5,12,5,0.2" Content="Start Test" Width="78" DockPanel.Dock="Left"
            Click="btnStart_Click"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>

<Button  x:Name="btnAbort" Content="Abort Test" Width="76" DockPanel.Dock="Right"
            IsEnabled="False" Click="btnAbort_Click" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,12,0,0.2"/>
```

What I want is to "Enable" or "Disable" the buttons by the value of the text box `txtCalls`. Let's say we have the logic such as:

```
if (txtCalls.Text == "")
{
    btnStart.IsEnabled = false;
    btnAbort.IsEnabled = true;
}
else
{
    btnStart.IsEnabled = true;
    btnAbort.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

By the way, I do have a class:

```
public class NotifyUIBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

But it is used by another combobox control `public class Combox : NotifyUIBase`

I don't know how to apply the text box NotifyPropertyChanged in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else stumbles over this answer in their quest for enabled buttons, Maximus' answer is much easier. This is a more MVVM focused way of handling the situation.

So I know the names here are something to be desired, but they're really doing simple things. Both buttons IsEnabled property are bound to the Text value of the processing text box. The converter then takes in the value, checks it against a target string, then returns a value indicating whether or not the button should be enabled. To that end, they could easily be named "IfValueIsProcessingThenTrueConverter" or something along those lines, but that seems messy too.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfPlayground.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfPlayground="clr-namespace:WpfPlayground"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <wpfPlayground:CanStartConverter x:Key="CanStartConverter" />
        <wpfPlayground:CanAbortConverter x:Key="CanAbortConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="btnStart" Margin="5,12,5,0.2" Content="Start Test" Width="78" DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
        IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=txtCalls, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource CanStartConverter}}"
        Click="btnStart_Click"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button  x:Name="btnAbort" Content="Abort Test" Width="76" DockPanel.Dock="Right"
         IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=txtCalls, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource CanAbortConverter}}" Click="btnAbort_Click" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,12,0,0.2"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ElementName=sliderCalls,
        Path=Value,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Name="ProcessingTextBox"/>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

CanStartConverter.cs

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfPlayground
{
    public class CanStartConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value.ToString() != "")
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }
    }
}
```

CanAbortConverter.cs

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfPlayground
{
    public class CanAbortConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value.ToString() == "")
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I already defined two buttons and I don't want to change them as they will be set in somewhere else as well. See my update code.

Comment: Would you please update your code according to my description?

Comment: When the text box value != 0, the start button is enabled and abort button is disabled. Thanks for updating the code, I will try it.

Comment: Alright, I made a couple of edits to more align with your scenario. I'm not 100% sure I got it though.

Comment: you can have it in one line of code,   return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()) ? true : false;

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Maximus. As an aside I like your answer, mine is coming from an MVVM background so it's a bit object-happy.

Comment: I got exceptions in `<Window.Resources>`. Basically it said the namespace prefix "xxxxx" is not defined. In your example, I guess it is `wpfPlayground`.

Comment: If you can do sth in xaml do it instead of creating numbers of converters containing one line of code.

Comment: @Love: Did you miss the xmlns:wpfPlayground="clr-namespace:WpfPlayground" in the Window tag?

Comment: @CBauer, Yes I forgot it. However after I added it, I got a new error. `The name "EmptyTextIsFalseConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:xxxxxxx"` The class name I used "EmptyTextIsFalseConverter".

Comment: Make sure it does exist and class is public.

Comment: You might want to just do a find and replace on that namespace to your actual project namespace. I'd also suggest changing to the code above because it's readable and supportable.

Comment: I cleaned the solution and rebuilt it. It is gone now.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <TextBox Name="txtCalls"/>
    <Button Content="Start">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=txtCalls, Path=Text.Length}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
    <Button Content="Abort">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=txtCalls,Path=Text.Length}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

or alternatively use this

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=txtCalls, Path=Text}" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
```

Comment: Not yet, as I said. I don't want to change my original buttons's description.

Comment: Well if you'are so attached to it. No change no gain.